# SQL Server: CREATE FUNCTION with declare variables inside

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I would like to create a `function` in `SQL Server`.

In this function, I need to define some `variables` and then use it in the SELECT.

SQL looks like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFussnction]  
(
    @path [nvarchar](10)
)
RETURNS TABLE

BEGIN
    DECLARE @xx varchar(50);
    SET @xx = 'Windows%';
RETURN 
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DataPath LIKE @path AND XX LIKE @xx;
END
```

But, it is not able to be created and the error says:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure MyFussnction, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.
```

Comment: You need to define the columns of the table that are being returned.  You are only saved this trouble for in-line table-valued functions.

Comment: you're forgetting an 'AS' before the 'BEGIN' and also what @GordonLinoff said.

Comment: You don't need variables here anyway. You can keep it as an inline function (usually more efficient) and use `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DataPath LIKE @path AND XX LIKE @path + '%';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define columns of table to return, then you can use declare, something like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFussnction]  (  
@path [nvarchar](10)
)
RETURNS @Mytable TABLE 
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    -- define other columns
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xx varchar(50);
    SET @xx = 'Windows%';

    Insert into @Mytable
    SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE DataPath LIKE @path AND XX LIKE @xx;
  RETURN; 
END
```